# Blockbuster bug with Unity and iPhone XR (specifically)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, core-motion, iphone-xr

more info!  this seems to be a real, fresh, unity bug

less than 12.1.2 … seems to work on all devices

12.1.2 .. **exhibits problem on an XR**

12.1.2 .. perfect on an 8Plus, X and others tested so far

Note - the identical behavior happens with recent Unity (all 2018.2) and the brand new Unity 2018.3

Filed with Unity - 1114664

---

Simply get the latest Unity so 2018.3 or 2018.2

Make a new blank project for iOS.

Make the scene empty - just a cube or such.

Build through to the latest Xcode (so, Version 10.1 (10B61)),

Plug in an ordinary XR and Run ...

It does seem to run, but these odd errors appear.

(I don't actually know if they are errors or warnings, or ??)

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread:
   -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 2496, TID: 691898, Thread name: 
   com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread,
   Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000021839f894 <redacted> + 56
5   CoreMotion                          0x000000021ec25040 CoreMotion + 307264
6   CoreMotion                          0x000000021ec25574 CoreMotion + 308596
```

1. It seems almost unbelievable Unity could make such a basic mistake, and anyway, there would be 10,000 discussions about it online already
2. I have tried on various phones, Macs etc etc .. what could it be??
3. It seems to be just a warning rather than a crash, but IDK. It's weird.

It's hard to see what CoreMotion has to do with anything (I clicked "off" the accelerometer from the Unity build, anyway).

[image]

What could be causing this error/warning on a iOS build?

Comment: You should log this as a Unity bug. You can log bugs from the mac app, via Help menu > Report a Bug...

Comment: sure man - i did of course!

Comment: I've been running into the same bug with ARKit and SceneKit and and iPhone XR. It happens when I try to programmatically instantiate view controllers from a View Controller running an ARKit Session. Then the UI freezes and I have to relaunch. Has anyone else seen this with SceneKit based apps or does a solution exist by now? 

Here is my call stack: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPW4v.png

Comment: fascinating, @Sebastian , thanks.  I have not tried the issue with AR myself.  :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact,  (January 2019)

the Unity dudes contacted me and explained that yeah, it's a bug!

So, that's that.

It does seem to be a warning - everything seems to proceed even though it happens.